# World Conqueror 2 - Windows 8 location of game save

Tags: windows-8, world-conqueror-2

I have installed World Conqueror 2 from easytech in Windows 8 however I need to reinstall the system but I cannot find directory where the game progress is saved. I need to backup my progress from this game.

I have found only game files that are located in

```
/ProgramFiles/WindowsApps
```

but there are no saves.

I have serched in *AppData* also, but no success.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a quick search in Appdata, I found the following folder:
34006EasyTech.WorldConqueror3_nz34nvfqxfk3r

Found in Appdata:Local:Packages

Enter it and you can find several things, including save files and editing slots for the World Conquest(which year, resources, army, etc.)

After looking through all the folders, there isn't a lot. The saves are written in code and editing them doesn't change anything. Some folders are empty and have no data or code written to them.

Though it isn't World Conqueror 2, there's a high probability it will be in the same %appdata% folder.

Hope I answered your question and I'll update you if I find anything new :)

My processor is Windows 8 with 400 GB of space.